# Actionscript (&#13;) vs Javascript (&#10;)

Tags: javascript, unicode, actionscript, carriage-return, linefeed

For same string actionScript's function `charCodeAt` returns unicode character `13` and javascript's function `charCodeAt` returns unicode character `10`. Is there a reason why a line feed is returned by JS and a carriage return is returned by AS. After reading a few answers online I have come to the conclusion that both of these do not have much difference, can anyone please explain why was this change made.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same string and hasn't been reformatted automatically? Maybe by the different text editor?

Comment: @skara9 Yes it is the same string I copy the string from the same excel sheet. Is there a major difference between line feed and carriage return?

Comment: The fact, that you copy the same text, does not mean it is not re-formatted when you paste in into... well, whatever you paste it into. Some editors treat CRLF as a single "new line" instruction, some use CR only, some even put two new lines for CRLF.

Comment: @arielBodyLotion What problem are you trying to solve by knowing this?

Comment: @VC.One I am just curious why the same text when converted using actionscript gives a different char and with javascript gives a different character and wanted to know why is this happening.